# How to identify and remove source of memory bloat?

Tags: javascript, json, memory, google-chrome-devtools, single-page-application

Our single-page application loads a lot of data from the server (a couple of hundred megs) but we're finding that on load JS is taking up 3x that. Looking at dev tools I'm finding it very difficult to determine the source of that extra memory.

Looking at the "statistics" view of the heap snapshot I see:

- Code: 59MB
- String: 214MB
- JS Arrays 24MB
- Typed Arrays: 24KB
- System Objects: 215MB
- Total: 741MB

A few questions:

1. If you add up the individual entries they come up to 651MB, where is the other 90MB coming from to get that total?
2. Do JSON strings that come down from the server ever get removed?
3. Best way to dig further to determine what is sucking up the memory?

Comment: There's language overhead in storing data since everything is an object in Javascript.  We'd have to see what exactly you're storing and how to store it to know what to suggest.

Comment: Most of the data coming down from the server are objects with around 60 keys. Each value is a number, string, or array of strings, or array of objects. The deepest nesting level is 3 deep Object -> Array -> Object. Nested objects are smaller (~5 properties). Right now we do have classes that "wrap" each object, but each class is very light. The class is a pointer to the underlying data object, some getter/setter functions and maybe one or two booleans.

Comment: There are in-depth articles on devtools site: [Fix Memory Problems](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/memory-problems/?hl=en) and [Profiling memory performance](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/heap-profiling).

Comment: It's also probable you won't be able to reduce the usage noticeably so consider offloading the data to IndexedDB/localStorage/sessionStorage.